# Is a hardfork more democratic then a softfork?

Tags: the-dao, hardforks, softfork

I was told that a hardfork would be a more democratic choice for Ethereum and the DAO problem then a Softfork was. Yet it has a greater impact to the system, as far as I understood. Which is true?
Am I right that any kind of fork is provided by the developers of Ethereum as only they got the knowledge to create it. So is it comparable to some kind of governance by the dev team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hard fork needs every node of the network to „vote“ for it whereas a soft fork only needs the support of the majority of the miners.
Nodes that don’t agree with the hard fork kind of leave the main chain and build a second chain. So it finnaly depends on the majority of nodes, which will be the actual main chain.
So as a hard fork needs all members of the network to make a decision, both is true: It’s a greater impact and it’s more democratic. A very interesting reading about that topic will you find [here](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/ethereums-vitalik-buterin-democratic-hard-fork-proves-mining-oligopoly-cannot-engage-censorship-1569079)